# Redirect rule in htaccess - unusual behavior

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

This is what I am trying to do. For every file abc.pdf stored in a directory domain.com/r, I want to give my user a friendly url - domain.com/abc

For this, i have implemented a redirect rule in .htaccess and written a php file. Below are the codes. Domain is "rocketresu.me"

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^rocketresu\.rocketresumebuilder\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.rocketresu\.rocketresumebuilder\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/rocketresu\.me\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^rocketresu\.me$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.rocketresu\.me$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/rocketresu\.me\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /data.php [L]
```

data.php

```
$parts1 = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$parts=parse_url("$parts1");
$path_parts=explode('/', $parts['path']);
 $aurl= $path_parts[count($path_parts)-1];

if($aurl=="")
  {
    $aurl= $path_parts[count($path_parts)-2];  
  }
  $lurl = strtolower($aurl);
  if(!ctype_digit($lurl))
  {
      $lurl="$lurl".".pdf";
  }

header("Location: http://rocketresu.me/r/$lurl");
```

---

This is working if i only use [http://rocketresu.me/abc](http://example.com). But if I use, http://**www**.rocketresu.me/abc, the code gives me an unexpected response!

Please can anybody help me?

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine for me on both cases. What's the unexpected response you're getting? Have you tried clearing your browser's cache?

Comment: here's what i am getting: 
when i type rocketresu.me/abc - the response in $lurl is abc.pdf which is ok
but when i type www.rocketresu.me/abc - the response in $lurl is data.php which is wrong. Where is the error? in htaccess? should i be worried about wildcard redirect or anything else?

Comment: For me `http://rocketresu.me/abc` and `http://www.rocketresu.me/abc` are behaving same

Comment: Thanks uri2x. I tried another system and it worked. Had to be a problem with my browser - tried clearing it but it is still giving me the same result!!